# Determine the distribution functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Two Players play with a fair dice. Both dice alternating. Player $1$ starts to dice and wins, if he dices a $1$. Player $2$ will win, if he dices a $5$ or $6$. If a Player will win, the other will dice until he gets the wanted total.

So let $X$ and $Y$ the number of cast of dice ($X$ for player $1$, $Y$ for player $2$). How can one get the distribution functions from $X$ and $Y$.

I do not know how to start here. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each player will roll until he gets a desired number (regardless of when the other player "wins"), the dsitributions of $x$ and $y$ are the corresponding geometric distributions:
$$
P(X=n) = \frac16\left(\frac56\right)^{n-1}\\
P(Y=m) = \frac13\left(\frac23\right)^{m-1}\\
$$
The problem becomes richer and the answer more complicated if modified in the following way:
"After any player has won, the other player continues rolling until he rolls a number that would be a win for *either* player (that is, 1, 5 or 6).